# OpenGL (ES) -- Rotating a circle renders only half the circle

Tags: graphics, opengl-es

I have successfully drawn circles and applied translations and scaling on them. When I rotate a circle by only 1 degree (or any degree), a half circle is drawn. I am using an ortho perspective. Why is this?

```
translateX = (float) (ratio * (xCoor - windowWidth / 2)) / (windowWidth / 2);
translateY = (float) (-(yCoor - windowHeight / 2)) / (windowHeight / 2);

gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexPointerCircleHR);
gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexPointerCircleHR);
gl11.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

circleRotation++;

gl11.glPushMatrix();
gl11.glColor4f(...);
gl11.glScalef(...);

gl11.glTranslatef(translateX, translateY, 0);
gl11.glRotatef(1,translateX,translateY, 0); //or circleRotation

gl11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, verticesCircle, 
  GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
gl11.glPopMatrix();
```

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`glRotate` receives the angle and a 3d vector that will be the **axis** of rotation ([Axis-angle representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis-angle_representation)).

If you're using orthogonal projection I assume you're doing a 2D rotation in front of the camera, and normally that's around the Z axis (0, 0, 1) or maybe (0, 0, -1).

You should probably replace your call with `glRotatef(circleRotation, 0, 0, 1)`.

Obviously without a texture or different vertex colors you won't notice a thing.

Comment: +1 also worth noting that `angle` is in radians, not degrees.

Comment: I thought the same, but checking the documentation I was surprised to read it's in degrees: http://www.khronos.org/opengles/documentation/opengles1_0/html/glRotate.html

Comment: It was a clipping issue. Palm meets forehead. And yeah, opengl es in in degrees, probably to make it easier for those not well versed in trig.

Comment: OpenGL is in degrees too! hehe! http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glRotate.xml